# With hydro, pcl can be installed alone?

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone.

**I'd like to install pcl stand-alone.

Could you tell me how to do it ?**

Since I've installed ros hydro through "desktop-full",
pcl(perception_pcl) has also being installed.
So I can see libpcl** under /usr/lib.

However, pcl/gpu is not found and I cannot try kinfu.
I gues that pcl installed with ros has a small part of full-pcl.
Then I'd like to install pcl stand-alone.

**I'm afraid that I will have confliction between pcl installed stand-alone and pcl installed with ros.

How can I install pcl stand-alone ?**

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157161/with-hydro,-pcl-can-be-installed-alone-?/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use KinFu with ROS see my answer in http://answers.ros.org/question/142461/pcl-kinfu-in-ros-hydro/

If you want to try KinFu in a PCL stand-alone version just clone the PCL repository, set DBUILD_GPU=ON and "make" it.
There is no reason for "make install".

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0